# Is there a way to capture/override Ctrl-R or F5 on IE using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I want to capture the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd> shortcut on the browser to prevent it from performing a browser refresh, but instead perform a custom refresh.

I was able to capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> on Safari and FF using:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e){
      if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.keyCode == 114) // Ctrl-R
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

But that doesn't work on IE. Is there any way to do this on IE?

*Update: For people who are asking why I am doing this in the first place: I just wanted to do a custom app refresh, but wanted to avoid having a "refresh" button because I kinda discourage using the refresh (We have a full page flex app). We ended up switching to F8 because F5 was just too hard to get working on all browsers.*

Comment: Do you just want to prevent reposting a form?

Comment: There are very good reasons for doing this. Consider a desktop-based time sheet data entry system where hundreds of users have been trained to use certain hot keys. You want to migrate the application to a web-based application having like-for-like constraints to the desktop application. For right or wrong, if that is management's final decision, then finding a way to override the default behaviour for function keys is mandatory. There are many other scenarios where you would want to override default keyboard behaviours, most of them I'd imagine being for internal web applications.

Comment: To add to Dale's list, there are lots of wearable devices in warehouses (running Pocket IE) that may not have touchscreens and need to make use of function keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Open JavaScript**

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

For certain keys (F1, F4), you have to open a new browser window without the address bar.

**Example**

Open a new window, without adornments:

```
window.open( 'webpage.html', 'TLA', 
'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=665' );
```

JavaScript to use the library:

```
var FALSE_FUNCTION = new Function( "return false" );

/**
 * Called to disable F1, F3, and F5.
 */
function disableShortcuts() {
  // Disable online help (the F1 key).
  //
  document.onhelp = FALSE_FUNCTION;
  window.onhelp = FALSE_FUNCTION;

  // Disable the F1, F3 and F5 keys. Without this, browsers that have these
  // function keys assigned to a specific behaviour (i.e., opening a search
  // tab, or refreshing the page) will continue to execute that behaviour.
  //
  document.onkeydown = function disableKeys() {
    // Disable F1, F3 and F5 (112, 114 and 116, respectively).
    //
    if( typeof event != 'undefined' ) {
      if( (event.keyCode == 112) ||
          (event.keyCode == 114) ||
          (event.keyCode == 116) ) {
        event.keyCode = 0;
        return false;
      }
    }
  };

  // For good measure, assign F1, F3, and F5 to functions that do nothing.
  //
  shortcut.add( "f1", FALSE_FUNCTION );
  shortcut.add( "f3", FALSE_FUNCTION );
  shortcut.add( "f5", FALSE_FUNCTION );
}
```

Inside `webpage.html`:

```
<body onload="disableShortcuts();">
```

Comment: I tried this out and it worked on IE8, Chrome, Safari, Opera and FF for me - for the F5 key.

Comment: Better: `var FALSE_FUNCTION = function() { return false; };`.

Answer (score 4):

There's no solid way to override the function-keys in browsers.

**Internet Explorer** has certain keys that can't be overridden, and certain keys which - even when overridden - still executes default behavior--like the F11 key, which switches to full-screen mode, and the F1 key which opens up a help-window.

**Chrome** does not allow you to use key-events at all.

**FireFox** is the most benign, but still sketchy--like Internet Explorer; there are still some keys and default behavior you cant override.

And finally.. **Opera**.. Which is about as difficult as Internet Explorer.

And the default behavior is different from version to version. It's like walking into a mine-field.. Blindfolded.. :)

Trying to override <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> / <kbd>F5</kbd> smells like bad design.

What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: Are you sure this works in Internet Explorer 8? I've had no luck doing just that.

Comment: @roosteronacid: On IE8, I had to make a one-line fix: add "var code;" after the line: "var func = function(e) {". IE8 is seems to be stricter with js.

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: Considering the fact that this can't be done across all A-grade browsers, it's bad design. I agree with the idea though.

Answer (score 2):

I beleave `document.body.onbeforeunload` is the way. You can even prevent user from leaving the page with that. Just not sure about how to detect if its a refresh or if he's actually surfing to somewhere else (document.location maybe?)

Answer (score 2):

Since the "how" has already been covered, I thought I'd mention that you have to be aware of the limits of using Javascript for something like this.

For example, in Safari (and possibly others), if you can get to the browser's *Search* input field, you can still issue shortcut key commands, but it's out of the scope of your Javascript. If the user does that, any key-event-eating code that you wrote will not be invoked, and the keypress will go through just fine.

So the solutions you find may work, but will almost universally be defeatable in some way by just using basic browser functions.

Answer (score 1):

YUI has a key handler that will work across all browsers

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/keylistener.html

I think the problem with the above code is that IE doesn't pass the event to the function.  It puts it in a global variable called window.event.

I suggest trying the YUI key listener, it will be a pretty clean solution and you don't need to use the whole library, just the pieces you need.

Answer (score 0):

for <kbd>f11</kbd> on IE
add checkkey on onkeydown event for the body `(onkeydown='return checkKey(event)' )`

```
function checkKey(e) {
 var alt =  e.altKey;
 var key = e.keyCode;
 var type = e.srcElement.type;
 ctrl = event.ctrlKey

 if ( alt || ((key == 8)&&(type != "text" && type != "textarea" && type != "password")) || (ctrl&&(key == 82)) || (key == 122) ) {
     event.keyCode = 0;
     e.keyCode = 0;
  event.returnValue = false;
                return false;
            }

        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `keyCode == 82`, not `114`? [Key codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) are not the same as ASCII/charCodes, so there's no upper/lower case consideration.

This worked for me (well, technically I used it with a JQuery keydown handler, not `document.onkeypress`):

```
document.onkeypress = function(e){
  if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.keyCode == 82) // Ctrl-R
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

And for all those crying "bad design" - I'm building a terminal emulator and want CTRL-R to match the Bash CTRL-R to search history, not refresh the page.  There are always use cases.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve a problem similar to this just by using JavaScript core only. The code is split into two parts, definition and implementation but the parts can be merged if it is needed.

**Definition**

```
/**
 * addKeyActions takes an array of objects that looks like this:
 * 
 * {
 *  keyCodes: [120], //F9
 *  modifiers: ['ctrlKey', 'shiftKey', 'altKey', 'altGraphKey', 'metaKey'], //Only legal modifiers
 *  callback: function(event){};
 * }
 * 
 * A good resource to find the keycodes you are looking for is:
 * http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes
 * 
 * However, there are more keycodes than written on this page, so if you can't find what you are looking for, 
 * I have provided a function that you can call to display the keycode for the current button pressed - alertKeyCodes
 * 
 * 
 * @Version 1.01
 */


/*
 * --HOW TO USE--
 * 
var allModifiersKeys = {
  keyCodes: [120, 121], //F9, F10
  modifiers: ['ctrlKey', 'shiftKey', 'altKey'],
  callback: function(event){alert("All modifiers pressed + Function-button!");}
};

var altKeys = {
  keyCodes: [122, 123], //F11, F12
  modifiers: ['altKey'],
  callback: function(event){alert("ALT pressed + Function-button!");}
};

var shiftCtrlKeys = {
  keyCodes: [116, 117], //F5, F6
  modifiers: ['ctrlKey', 'shiftKey'],
  callback: function(event){alert("CTRL+SHIFT+Function-button pressed!");}
};

var noModifierKeys = {
  keyCodes: [118, 119], //F7, F8
  callback: function(event){preventDefaultEventPropagation(); alert("Function-button!");} //Do not forget to also declare the preventDefaultEventPropagation-function 
  //that is listed below for this example to work
};

addKeyActions([allModifiersKeys, altKeys, shiftCtrlKeys, noModifierKeys]);

*/

function addKeyActions(key){

    document.onkeydown = function(){
        var matchingKeyCode = findMatchingKeyCode();
        var match = matchModifiers(matchingKeyCode);
        if(match){
            matchingKeyCode.callback(event);
        }
    };

    function findMatchingKeyCode(){
        var eventKeyCode = event.keyCode || event.which || event.charCode;
        var returnVal;
        for(var i=0; i<key.length; i++){
            var tempKey = key[i];
            var containsKeyCode = isValueInArray(eventKeyCode, tempKey.keyCodes);
            if(containsKeyCode){
                returnVal = tempKey;
            }
        }
        return returnVal;
    }

    function isValueInArray(value, array){
        var hasValue = false;
        for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
            var tempValue = array[i];
            if(tempValue === value){
                hasValue = true;
            }
        }
        return hasValue;
    }

    function matchModifiers(key){
        var match = false;
        if(key != undefined){
            match = true;
            if(key.modifiers instanceof Array){
                for(var i=0; i<key.modifiers.length; i++){
                    var modifier = key.modifiers[i];
                    match = match && event[modifier];   
                }
            }
        }
        return match;
    }
}

/**
 * Useful callbacks/functions are listed below 
 */
function preventDefaultEventPropagation(){

    if(event.cancelBubble) event.cancelBubble = true;
    if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
    if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    event.returnValue = false;
    event.keyCode = 0;
    return false;
}

/**
 * Useful methods during developement 
 */
function alertKeyCodes(){
    document.onkeydown = function(){
        alert(event.keyCode || event.which || event.charCode);
        if(event.cancelBubble) event.cancelBubble = true;
        if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
        if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

        event.returnValue = false;
        event.keyCode = 0;
        return false;
    };
}
```

**Implementation**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var SingleKeys = {
            keyCodes: [114, 116, 121, 122], //F3, F5, F10, F11
            callback: function(event){return preventDefaultEventPropagation();}
        };

        var BackspaceKeys = {
            keyCodes: [8], //Backspace
            callback: function(event){
                var sourceOfEvent = event.target || event.srcElement;
                if(sourceOfEvent.tagName == "BODY"){
                    return preventDefaultEventPropagation();
                }
            }
        };
        var EnterKeys = {
                keyCodes: [13], //Enter
                callback: function(event){
                    var sourceOfEvent = event.target || event.srcElement;
                    if(sourceOfEvent.tagName == "BODY"){
                        return preventDefaultEventPropagation();
                    }
                    if(sourceOfEvent.tagName == "INPUT" && sourceOfEvent.type == "text"){
                        return preventDefaultEventPropagation();
                    }
                }
        };

        var AltKeys = {
            keyCodes: [36, 37, 39], //Home, Left, Right
            modifiers: ['altKey'],
            callback: function(event){return preventDefaultEventPropagation();}
        };

        var CtrlKeys = {
            keyCodes: [66, 68, 69, 72, 73, 76, 78, 79, 82], //B, D, E, H, I, L, N, O, R
            modifiers: ['ctrlKey'],
            callback: function(event){return preventDefaultEventPropagation();}
        };

        addKeyActions([SingleKeys, BackspaceKeys, EnterKeys, AltKeys,CtrlKeys]);
});
```

Just add the keyCode you wish to intercept and edit the callback accordingly