# Disable F5 Ctr+F5 and Ctrl+R in IE8 while input box is focused

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I want to disable web page refresh while text box is focused
the code I'm using is this which works great for other shortcuts
except that:

BTW I want to achieve this by plain JavaScript no JQuery and no JavaScript 
Frameworks.

```
  document.onkeydown = keyDown  //control chars
document.onkeypress = keyDown   //any char/number

function keyDown(e) {

        //74=j, 75=k, 78=n, 84=t
        var forbiddenCtrlKeys = new Array(74,75,78, 84);
        //37=left_arrow, 39=right_arrow
        var forbiddenAltKeys = new Array(37,39);
        //8=backspace, 116=F5
        var forbiddenSingleKeys = new Array(8,116);
        //per le textbox 116=F5
        var forbiddenTextBoxKeys = new Array(116);

        key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE

              if(window.event.ctrlKey){ //ctrl
                    isCtrl = true;
                    isAlt = false

                    checkVal(forbiddenCtrlKeys,window.event.keyCode);
              }
              else if(window.event.altKey){ //alt
                    isCtrl = false;
                    isAlt = true;
                    checkVal(forbiddenAltKeys,window.event.keyCode);
              }

              else{ //other

                    isCtrl = false;
                    isAlt = false;
                    var element = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                    var curr = document.activeElement
                    if(curr.tagName=="INPUT")
                    alert(curr.tagName);

                    if((element != 'input' && element != 'textarea') || $(e.target).attr("readonly")){
                        alert(window.event.keyCode);
                        checkVal(forbiddenSingleKeys,window.event.keyCode); 
                    }
                    if(document.event.keyCode==116){
                        alert(window.event.keyCode);
                        document.event.keyCode=0;
                        checkVal(forbiddenTextBoxKeys,window.event.keyCode);
                    }       
              }
}

function checkVal(set,key){


        for(i in set)
        {
        //case-insensitive comparison
            if(String.fromCharCode(set[i]).toLowerCase() == String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase())
                        {
                                alert('This key combination has been disabled.');
                                window.event.returnValue =        false;    
                                window.event.keyCode = 0;
                                return true;
                        }
        }
}
```

So what I've tried to achieve in the else case is whenever I try to press F5 disable it 
but it doesn't works, any insight would be highly appreciated

Comment: `var forbiddenTextBoxKeys = new Array(116);` behaves differently you expect, it creates a new arrray which length is 116. Use literals instead: `var forbiddenTextBoxKeys = [116];`. Also `onkeyup` is more effective, when doing things like this. Also checking `CTRL` and `ALT` fails, they have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: What's the difference bewteen onkeyup and onkeydown in my given context ?

Comment: Timing, but nevermind, I'm afraid this won't work anyway, you can't cancel key events at all. Please see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536940%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . BTW, all properties of `window.event` are read-only, you can't set `window.event.keyCode = 0;`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to capture/override Ctrl-R or F5 on IE using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400528/is-there-a-way-to-capture-override-ctrl-r-or-f5-on-ie-using-javascript)

Comment: @DonalFellows No it's not because my case regards only input text boxes so before posting wrong alert please consider reading my question.