# asp.net mvc prevent multiple form posts by refrshing page w/ f5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 website with a HTML form where user can a pretty large file (xxx kb).  Some data from this file should be inserted into the data base and the response should be provided to user.

Everything works fine except when the user refreshes page by pressing F5.  Then data are inserted into data base multiple times.  I have disabled submit button after first submit, but problem with F5 refresh remains.

I have tried Post-Redirect-Get but it doesn't work due to that large file. What is the solution to prevent duplicate entries while still allowing me to upload the file?

Answer (score 0):

Capturing keyboard shortcuts using javascript is described in this previous answer.  I cannot attest as to whether this is ulitmately the best solution to your problem, but addresses specifically what you asked.

[Is there a way to capture/override Ctrl-R or F5 on IE using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400528/is-there-a-way-to-capture-override-ctrl-r-or-f5-on-ie-using-javascript)