# JQuery code working on Chrome but not IE version 8.0.7601.17514

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

I have a simple jQuery script using the mousetrap.js library (http://craig.is/killing/mice) designed to block out a set of keys. This code works fine in Chrome and I suspect that it also works in Firefox. This is due to that the event `cancelBubble`, `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` is not defined for my set of keys. Again <kbd>F5</kbd> is only one of approximately 10-15 keys. I can provide the full array of keys which I wish to lock if that is necessary. I have tried to use the `JQuery.event.fix(e)` but that did not work and the event still got fired. Has anyone of you encountered this problem or a similar one, I would be very pleased if someone could help me with this issue.

Just to be clear, I am using IE version 8.0.7601.17514 and an update is not in question (unfortunately) because this is a corporate computer and our system requires that we block the keys.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Mousetrap.bind(['f5'], function(e) {
        if(e.cancelBubble) e.cancelBubble = true;
        if(e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
        if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: What is your jQuery version ?

Comment: Are they all failing to be blocked, or is it specific keys.

Comment: This might be an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400528/is-there-a-way-to-capture-override-ctrl-r-or-f5-on-ie-using-javascript Also, you should likely `return false` as well in your event handler.

Comment: @KevinB Most likely due to the fact that event.preventDefault and the other ones are not getting fired at all. I am unable to verify this right now but I will check and come back to you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution to the problem. It is done with plain old Javascript and should be compatible with most browsers. Feel free to report if it doesn't.

```
/**
 * addKeyActions takes an array of objects that looks like this:
 * 
 * {
 *  keyCodes: [120], //F9
 *  modifiers: ['ctrlKey', 'shiftKey', 'altKey', 'altGraphKey', 'metaKey'], //Only legal modifiers
 *  callback: function(event){};
 * }
 * 
 * A good resource to find the keycodes you are looking for is:
 * http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes
 * 
 * However, there are more keycodes than written on this page, so if you can't find what you are looking for, 
 * I have provided a function that you can call to display the keycode for the current button pressed - alertKeyCodes
 * 
 * 
 * @Version 1.01
 */


/*
 * --HOW TO USE--
 * 
var allModifiersKeys = {
  keyCodes: [120, 121], //F9, F10
  modifiers: ['ctrlKey', 'shiftKey', 'altKey'],
  callback: function(event){alert("All modifiers pressed + Function-button!");}
};

var altKeys = {
  keyCodes: [122, 123], //F11, F12
  modifiers: ['altKey'],
  callback: function(event){alert("ALT pressed + Function-button!");}
};

var shiftCtrlKeys = {
  keyCodes: [116, 117], //F5, F6
  modifiers: ['ctrlKey', 'shiftKey'],
  callback: function(event){alert("CTRL+SHIFT+Function-button pressed!");}
};

var noModifierKeys = {
  keyCodes: [118, 119], //F7, F8
  callback: function(event){preventDefaultEventPropagation(); alert("Function-button!");} //Do not forget to also declare the preventDefaultEventPropagation-function 
  //that is listed below for this example to work
};

addKeyActions([allModifiersKeys, altKeys, shiftCtrlKeys, noModifierKeys]);

*/

function addKeyActions(key){

    document.onkeydown = function(){
        var matchingKeyCode = findMatchingKeyCode();
        var match = matchModifiers(matchingKeyCode);
        if(match){
            matchingKeyCode.callback(event);
        }
    };

    function findMatchingKeyCode(){
        var eventKeyCode = event.keyCode || event.which || event.charCode;
        var returnVal;
        for(var i=0; i<key.length; i++){
            var tempKey = key[i];
            var containsKeyCode = isValueInArray(eventKeyCode, tempKey.keyCodes);
            if(containsKeyCode){
                returnVal = tempKey;
            }
        }
        return returnVal;
    }

    function isValueInArray(value, array){
        var hasValue = false;
        for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
            var tempValue = array[i];
            if(tempValue === value){
                hasValue = true;
            }
        }
        return hasValue;
    }

    function matchModifiers(key){
        var match = false;
        if(key != undefined){
            match = true;
            if(key.modifiers instanceof Array){
                for(var i=0; i<key.modifiers.length; i++){
                    var modifier = key.modifiers[i];
                    match = match && event[modifier];   
                }
            }
        }
        return match;
    }
}

/**
 * Useful callbacks/functions are listed below 
 */
function preventDefaultEventPropagation(){

    if(event.cancelBubble) event.cancelBubble = true;
    if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
    if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    event.returnValue = false;
    event.keyCode = 0;
    return false;
}

/**
 * Useful methods during developement 
 */
function alertKeyCodes(){
    document.onkeydown = function(){
        alert(event.keyCode || event.which || event.charCode);
        if(event.cancelBubble) event.cancelBubble = true;
        if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
        if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

        event.returnValue = false;
        event.keyCode = 0;
        return false;
    };
}
```

Note that the definition of the functions and the usage locations are in 2 separate files. One being the invocation starting with document ready and the definition above it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var SingleKeys = {
            keyCodes: [114, 116, 121, 122], //F3, F5, F10, F11
            callback: function(event){return preventDefaultEventPropagation();}
        };

        var BackspaceKeys = {
            keyCodes: [8], //Backspace
            callback: function(event){
                var sourceOfEvent = event.target || event.srcElement;
                if(sourceOfEvent.tagName == "BODY"){
                    return preventDefaultEventPropagation();
                }
            }
        };
        var EnterKeys = {
                keyCodes: [13], //Enter
                callback: function(event){
                    var sourceOfEvent = event.target || event.srcElement;
                    if(sourceOfEvent.tagName == "BODY"){
                        return preventDefaultEventPropagation();
                    }
                    if(sourceOfEvent.tagName == "INPUT" && sourceOfEvent.type == "text"){
                        return preventDefaultEventPropagation();
                    }
                }
        };

        var AltKeys = {
            keyCodes: [36, 37, 39], //Home, Left, Right
            modifiers: ['altKey'],
            callback: function(event){return preventDefaultEventPropagation();}
        };

        var CtrlKeys = {
            keyCodes: [66, 68, 69, 72, 73, 76, 78, 79, 82], //B, D, E, H, I, L, N, O, R
            modifiers: ['ctrlKey'],
            callback: function(event){return preventDefaultEventPropagation();}
        };

        addKeyActions([SingleKeys, BackspaceKeys, EnterKeys, AltKeys, CtrlKeys]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery 2, **"this version leaves behind the older Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8 browsers."** [...] **"But don’t worry, the jQuery team still supports the 1.x branch which does run on IE 6/7/8."**

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

Comment: Woops! Forgot to mention that. I am running JQuery version 1.10.2.

Answer (score 0):

> i do not know about mousetrap, but you can look at the keycode of the event being fired and stopPropagation etc, this approach may be a bit more friendly to older browsers, if mousetrap doesnt support them (and means you dont need another library).

```
$(window).on('keyup', function(event) {
     if (event.keyCode ===  19) { //19 is f5 in your example
         event.stopPropagation();
         //etc..
     }
});
```

or for multiple keycodes something like

```
$(window).on('keyup', function(event) {

     var blockedKeys = [19, 18, 17]; 

     if (blockedKeys.indexOf(event.keyCode) > -1) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         //etc..
     }
});
```

see [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) for full list of keycodes

Comment: Thanks for very nice examples! I tried a similar approach before mousetrap but I failed when combining keys with CTRL, but I think that has been addressed higher up in the thread (here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400528/is-there-a-way-to-capture-override-ctrl-r-or-f5-on-ie-using-javascript). If I'm not misremembering I tried using that very example to combine modifierkeys but what happened was that the stop got fired when ctrl was pushed. To clarify. I don't think single keys are a big issue but rather keys combined with modifiers such as ctrl, alt or shift.

Comment: ah ok fair enough, i have'nt tried with combos of keys, certainly not in IE8 anyway

Comment: I see. I will happily report my findings when I come to any kind of useful conclusion, positive or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

We managed to solve the issue with standard javascript and avoiding both jquery and Mousetrap by doing the following:

```
function preventBubbling(event){

    if(event.cancelBubble) event.cancelBubble = true;
    if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
    if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    event.returnValue = false;
    event.keyCode = 0;
    return false;
}

document.onkeydown = function(){
    switch (event.keyCode){
    case 8: //Backspace
    case 13: //Enter
    case 114: //F3
    case 116: //F5
    case 121: //F10
    case 122: //F11
        return preventBubbling(event);

    case 66: //B+ctrl
    case 68: //D+ctrl
    case 69: //E+ctrl
    case 72: //H+ctrl
    case 73: //I+ctrl
    case 76: //L+ctrl
    case 78: //N+ctrl
    case 79: //O+ctrl
    case 82: //R+ctrl
        if(event.ctrlKey){
            return preventBubbling(event);
        }

    case 36: //Home +alt
    case 37: //Left +alt
    case 39: //Right +alt
        if(event.altKey){
            return preventBubbling(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to what @Nadrendion said we added a couple of lines just below backspace and enter. Those lines reads as follows <br>
`var sourceOfEvent = event.target || event.srcElement;
   if(sourceOfEvent.tagName == "BODY"){
    return preventBubbling(event);
   }
   break;`<br>
those lines make sure that backpace and enter are valid keys when needed to i.e. if cursor is at input field for backspace and if a button is selected the enter key is valid. The enter key is also valid in an input field but not in the body where backspace is defined as 'go back one step' in history.